# Can Fanout method be replaced by ref.orderByChild(key).equalTo(value) in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, database, nosql

In my app, users can upload pictures in groups.

There are two pages that display these pictures.

I have two requirements.

1. Display a list of images uploaded by a user.
2. Display a list of images uploaded on a group.

From what I learned on firebase tutorial, I learned data fanout is a good redundancy mechanics that'll speed up the lookup time at the cost of writing speed which is fine because there are more lookup requests than writing requests. So I created the following structure.

**Fanout Method**

```
{
    "user": [
       {key: "user_key_1"},
       {key: "user_key_2"},
       {key: "user_key_3"},
    ],
    "group": [
       {key: "group_key_1"},
       {key: "group_key_2"}
   ],
    "post": [
       {
        key: "post_key_1"
        },
       {
        key: "post_key_2"
        },
       {
        key: "post_key_3"
        },
    ],
    "user-post": {
       user_key_1:[{
        key: "post_key_1"
       }],
       user_key_2:[{
        key: "post_key_2"
       },{
        key: "post_key_3"
       }]
    },
    "group-post": {
       group_key_1:[{
        key: "post_key_2"
       }],
       group_key_2:[{
        key: "post_key_1"
       },{
        key: "post_key_3"
       }]
    },
}
```

**Code to Retrieve**

```
String userKey = ...;
database.child("user-post").child(userKey).addValueEventListener(...)
// returns list of posts owned by userKey

String groupKey = ...;
database.child("group-post").child(groupKey).addValueEventListener(...)
// returns list of posts posted on groupKey
```

But this caused significant headache since if you want to update the post and you have the reference to the post from group-post query, you'd have to update the user-post side and vice versa.

This requires me to add *userKey* and *groupKey* to the post datastructure so the cloud function to find the other other side quickly. Also I might need something like *lastUpdatedTimestamp* to see who is outdated.

```
exports.userPostToBusinessPost = functions.database.ref('/user-post/{userKey}')
    .onWrite(event => {
      const userPostRef = event.data.val();
      const businessPostRef = event.data.adminRef.root.child('business-post').child(post.businessKey);
      if(userPostRef.lastUpdatedTimestamp <= businessPostRef.lastUpdatedTimestamp){
          return;
      }else{
          return businessPost.set(event.data);
      }
    });

exports.businessPostToUserPost = functions.database.ref('/business-post/{businessKey}')
    .onWrite(event => {
      const businessPostRef = event.data.val();
      const userPostRef = event.data.adminRef.root.child('user-post').child(post.userKey);
      if(userPostRef.lastUpdatedTimestamp <= businessPostRef.lastUpdatedTimestamp){
          return;
      }else{
          return userPostRef.set(event.data);
      }
    });
```

After writing all this, I started feeling exhausted.
I tried again.
How about instead, I just use .orderBy(key).equalTo(value) to retrieve non fanout data?

**No Fanout Method**

```
{
    "user": [
       {key: "user_key_1"},
       {key: "user_key_2"},
       {key: "user_key_3"},
    ],
    "group": [
       {key: "group_key_1"},
       {key: "group_key_2"},
   ],
    "post": [
       {
        key: "post_key_1"
        groupKey: "group_key_2"
        userKey: "user_key_1"
        },
       {
        key: "post_key_2"
        groupKey: "group_key_1"
        userKey: "user_key_2"
        },
       {
        key: "post_key_3"
        groupKey: "group_key_2"
        userKey: "user_key_2"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Code to Retrieve**

```
String userKey = ...;
databaseReference.child("post").orderByChild("userKey").equalTo(userKey).addValueEventListener(...)
// returns list of posts owned by userKey

String groupKey = ...;
databaseReference.child("post").orderByChild("groupKey").equalTo(groupKey).addValueEventListener(...)
// returns list of posts posted on groupKey
```

Should I still use fanout method? Is that better because "orderByChild" costs a lot? If so, why would Firebase have an an implicit fanout mechanism where any json object is sorted by all of its the children keys whenever we save some data so developers don't have to manage fanout ourselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want a user to have read access to posts that are owned by themselves.

We have

```
"post": [
       {
        key: "post_key_1"
        groupKey: "group_key_2"
        userKey: "user_key_1"
        },
       {
        key: "post_key_2"
        groupKey: "group_key_1"
        userKey: "user_key_2"
        },
       {
        key: "post_key_3"
        groupKey: "group_key_2"
        userKey: "user_key_2"
        }
    ]
```

user_key_1 wants to access post.
But we don't want her to see user_key_2.
If we want to use orderBy, we would have to call

```
...
.child("post").orderBy("userKey").equalTo("user_key_2");
```

But since we can't give selective validation rule within the value (In this case, the post array), we'd end up having to do the following.

```
"post":{
   .read:true,
   .write:true
}
```

A malicious hacker can access other things, so we will end up with a database that can be exposed.
So to use validation rule the way it is intended, avoid orderBy and use data replication.

A hint to anyone who thinks it should be done on the server side,
Here's how I did one.

exports.multiUpdate = functions.database.ref('/post/{postKey}').onWrite(event => {
       var post = event.data.val();

var fanoutObject = {};

```
    fanoutObject['/user-post/'+ post.authorUid+"/"+post.key] = post;
    fanoutObject['/group-post/'+post.groupKey+"/"+post.key] = post;

   return event.data.adminRef.root.update(fanoutObject);
```

});

This way is great since you just have to always save onto the "/post/" on the client side and that will update the corresponding locations as well.